# VBA Word - Keep table from growing outside the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two buttons, one of which creates a table in the word document and the other adds a column to the table. My problem is that after i create my table and try to add a column to it the table grows outside of the document instead of fitting the columns inside the document.

```
Sub CreateTable(columns As Long)
    Dim t As Table
    Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=columns, _
            DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
End Sub

Sub AddColumn()
    Selection.InsertColumnsRight
End Sub
```

Am I missing some parameter when creating the table? Or am I adding the column incorrectly?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that I recorded a macro of trying the same thing with the built-in tools. And what I got was more or less exactly like I've done it. Using Selection.InsertColumnsRight and the same parameters when creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the column to the current "selection" aka where the cursor icon is basically blinking waiting for input if you were typing normally. In this case it would be to the right of the table you just inserted.

To fix this I would either keep a reference to your table and add to it that way, or look it up by doing something like `ActiveDocument.Tables(1)`

Take a look here [for an example of how to add columns.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Word/AddingaColumntoaTable.htm)

Comment: I tried what you suggested, with a small change. But it still works the same way as before.
Dim t As Table
Set t = Selection.Tables(1)
With t
.columns.Add BeforeColumn:=Selection.columns
End With

Answer (score 0):

You set the auto fit to "Fixed" when you initially create the table. If you want the table to fit on the page, it needs to be set to "Window". If you don't want to set that initially (maybe not all tables have columns added to them), you can do it after adding a column.

```
Sub AddColumn()
Dim objTable As Table

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        Set objTable = Selection.Tables(1)
        Selection.InsertColumnsRight
        objTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    End If
End Sub
```

This also checks that the selection is actually in a table before it does anything; otherwise you run the risk of throwing an error.

Comment: I've tried using all the auto fit modes, but still no luck.
I have no idea why it's not working.
For now I just resize the table after a column has been added, but its not a very good solution to the problem.

Comment: Using the code in my answer, the table doesn't autofit? What version of Word are you using?